# Atlas MongoDB view M0 cluster db logs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I know there is no option to download mongodb M0 cluster db logs. Is there any way to view that M0 cluster database logs ?

Comment: You can try the getLog command - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/getLog/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.getLog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not.

M0 (and maybe M5?) are shared tiers, which means there is a single underlying mongod process that serves many customers' clusters.  Atlas does some kind of translation magic so that the data for the multiple customers is kept distinct and is only accessible according to your security settings.

If you did have access to the mongod log, that would imply that every other customer sharing that mongod also has access to your logs, which seems like it would be an enormous privacy violation.

So nobody gets access to the mongod logs on a shared cluster.